# Django, including one template in another results TemplateDoesNotExist at /

Tags: python, django, templates

I'm using Django 3.0.4, Python, 3.8, VS Code and Windows 10. I want to include the post_list.html and post_new.html templates in my base.html file. I need to show them all on the main website. I just want to have one page comprising these templates. I think this would allow me to have an audio file playing consistently even when I submit a post - page would not reload I believe (but I haven't achieved this phase of project yet).

I started achieving my goal by including my template post_new.html in the base.html. However, I spinned up the server, visited main site and I encountered a problem:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /

post_new.html

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:     3.0.4
Exception Type:     TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    

post_new.html

Exception Location:     C:\Users\marecki\Desktop\mareknasz_projekt\evviva_larte\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py in reraise, line 84
Python Executable:  C:\Users\marecki\Desktop\mareknasz_projekt\evviva_larte\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version:     3.8.0
Python Path:    

['C:\\Users\\marecki\\Desktop\\mareknasz_projekt\\evviva_larte\\ewiwa',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python38-32\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python38-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python38-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python38-32',
 'C:\\Users\\marecki\\Desktop\\mareknasz_projekt\\evviva_larte\\venv',
 'C:\\Users\\marecki\\Desktop\\mareknasz_projekt\\evviva_larte\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']

Server time:    Wed, 8 Apr 2020 12:57:51 +0200
```

In settings.py I have included the following:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
        ],
```

This is a base.html:

```
{% load static %}
{% include "post_new.html" %}
<html>
    <head>        
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static '/assets/favicon-32x32.png' %}" />   
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Audiowide&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amarante&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-6khuMg9gaYr5AxOqhkVIODVIvm9ynTT5J4V1cfthmT+emCG6yVmEZsRHdxlotUnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">      
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/howler/2.1.3/howler.core.min.js"></script>
        <title>miśnia i maśnia</title>  
        </head>
    <body>       
        <div class="page-header">
            <a href="{% url 'post_new' %}" class="top-menu"><span>
                <svg class="bi bi-plus-circle" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 3.5a.5.5 0 01.5.5v4a.5.5 0 01-.5.5H4a.5.5 0 010-1h3.5V4a.5.5 0 01.5-.5z" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.5 8a.5.5 0 01.5-.5h4a.5.5 0 010 1H8.5V12a.5.5 0 01-1 0V8z" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 15A7 7 0 108 1a7 7 0 000 14zm0 1A8 8 0 108 0a8 8 0 000 16z" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
                  </svg>
            </span></a>
            <h1><a href="/">prezentacja zależności w konkursie czterech zgłośni</a></h1>        
        </div>
        <div class="content-container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    {% block content %}                                   
                    {% endblock %}   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!-- <script>
            function playMusic(){
            music.play();
            }
            </script>
          <html>        
            <audio id="music" loop src="{% static '/assets/joint_stereo.mp3' %}" autoplay> </audio>
            </html> -->




    </body>
</html>
```

This is post_new.html:

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}    
    <form method="POST" class="post-form" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger">en garde</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

This is post_list.html

```
      {% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
      {% block content %}
            {% for post in posts %}
                <div class="post">
                    <div class="author">
                        <p>przez: {{ post.author }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-content">
                        <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
         {% endblock %}
```

These are my urls.py (showing the text file is not working):

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    path('post/new/', views.post_new, name='post_new'), 
    path('poem/', views.poem, name='poem'),     
]
```

The views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post
from .forms import PostForm
from django.http.response import HttpResponseRedirect


def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-created_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})  

def post_new(request):   
    if request.method == "POST":    
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)            
            post.save()    
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')          
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_new.html', {'form': form})

def poem(request):
    f = open('blog\static\\assets\ewiwa.txt', 'r', encoding="latin-1")
    file_content = f.read()
    f.close()
    context = {'file_content': file_content}
    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

And that's how I arranged my files:

[image]

I think I need to say what my website should do: On the main site I expect to have a post list, a form and text file. After submitting a post, there should be no reloading and redirecting anywhere.

Best regards,
Mark, the starting programmist

Comment: You have a circular import; in `post_new.html` you write `extends blog/base.html`, but in `base.html` you have `include post_new.html`. You cannot have both.

Comment: Deletion of the `extends` clauses from both templates when the two `include` clauses become present results with only post_list.html is present, without any formatting, and with no navbar

Comment: Then rewrite the templates so that you don't need a circular import.